# Object with better efficiency than JTable

Tags: java, performance, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I would like to create visualization of database. It's a full-desktop application, and it looks similar to Excel. When i put into my JTable database visualization 100 rows, each one with 6 columns, the application is crushing down. Is there a better class for such a task? Or some other smarter way?

Thats the way i do it:

```
import PodklasyInterfejsu.Menu;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class OknoGlowne extends JFrame 
{    
    public Okno() 
    {
        // ustawienie rozmiaru okna na 100% 
        JFrame Okno = new JFrame(); 

        Okno.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        Okno.setTitle("Archiwum Stomatologiczne");


        Toolkit zestaw = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
        Dimension rozmiarEkranu = zestaw.getScreenSize();
        int wysEkranu = rozmiarEkranu.height;
        int szerEkranu = rozmiarEkranu.width;
        Okno.setSize(szerEkranu, wysEkranu - 60);                              


        Container powZawartosci = getContentPane();

        // Panel Górnego Menu:
        Menu GorneMenu = new Menu();
        Okno.setJMenuBar(GorneMenu);

        // Wizualizacja bazy w tabeli:

        JTable tabela = new JTable(komorki, nazwyKolumn);
        tabela.setAutoCreateRowSorter(true);
        Okno.add(new JScrollPane(tabela), BorderLayout.CENTER);

        Okno.setVisible(true);

    }
        private Object[][] komorki = new Object [10][];
        private String[] nazwyKolumn = {"Nazwisko", "Imię", "Pesel", "Płeć", "Data urodzenia", "Adres", "Kontakt"};
}
```

Comment: What are you using for your table model? I've put far more data than that into a JTable with custom table models and had no problems. By custom table model I mean classes that extend AbstractTableModel.

Comment: I've had JTables with thousands of rows with no performance hit. Are you using your own TableModel or the DefaultTableModel that comes with JTable? 

Where is this performance hit coming? Painting of the table?

Comment: What do you mean crashing down? Exception? You won't have trouble with a JTable holding only 100 rows! Are you sure it is not your model that has got a problem?

Comment: Are you sure that the JTable is where the bottleneck is? Have you profiled the app? My experience has been that a JTable should easily handle this amount of information. More often than not, the slow down is on the database or database interaction side, and it will be prudent to do this part of your code off of the Swing event thread, the EDT.

Comment: Please provide some data that can show what's actually happening, because "crushing down" can mean a lot of things.

Comment: by crushing down i mean, that when i run my project in NetBeans, i've got big problems with program fluency.

Comment: @Noran: it sounds like you've got threading issues as I've noted above, but it's still a bit hard to say. why not simply run your database code in a background thread such as one provided by a SwingWorker?

Comment: What does "program fluency" mean? I don't see anything with the posted code that would cause a problem. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem. Words like "crushing down", "fluency" don't mean anything to me.

Comment: OK, time to be blunt: The posted code is a mess, no worse than that, it's a friggin mess, mangled names, constructor name different from class names, undeclared variables,... I could go on and on. Please don't waste our times posting code this terrible. Post *real* code.

Comment: I can't fluently scroll my scrollbar. I also can't move smaller pop-up windows from menu, without painting problems with it. It looks like ghost movement, some kind of tale going behind moving window. Sometimes window is in right corner of screen, but it's "shadow" stays in left one. I was translating this code from deferent language for you guys. Now the original one is posted.

Comment: If the problem is threading issues, feel free to drop the following assert statements into your code:
assert SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread();  (make sure you run your java program with "-ea" as your VM arg so assertions aren't ignored.

Comment: You still have a JFrame variable name that is the same as the class name and the constructor that it's in -- why?

Comment: i didn't know that that's wrong.

Comment: It's wrong and very confusing. If you have `OknoGlowne.myMethod();` is this a static method called on the OknoGlowne class or an instance method called on the OknoGlowne variable? How are we supposed to know? How is the compiler and the JVM supposed to know?

Comment: But as for your problem, I still feel that using a SwingWorker properly would help a great deal. Again, likely it's the database interactions that are slowing you down.

Comment: The strangest thing is, that there are no database iteractions yet. The code looks like a pasted in main post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One problem in the code above is that your data 2-d Object[10][] array, komorki, doesn't match  your column String[] array, nazwyKolumn. You have 7 columns and need 7 as the first array index for your Object array.  Consider changing this:

```
private Object[][] komorki = new Object[10][];
private String[] nazwyKolumn = { "Nazwisko", "Imię", "Pesel", "Płeć",
     "Data urodzenia", "Adres", "Kontakt" };
```

to this:

```
// !! private Object[][] komorki = new Object[10][];
private Object[][] komorki = new Object[10][7]; //!!
private String[] nazwyKolumn = { "Nazwisko", "Imię", "Pesel", "Płeć",
     "Data urodzenia", "Adres", "Kontakt" };
```

for starters.

Comment: Yes! Thats the answer, i missed that. After little modification it works as it's supposed to:

Comment: private Object[][] komorki = new Object[100][7];

Comment: +1 well spotted. See also [Christmas Tree Applications](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/ChristmasTree/); it's rarely needed, but handy to know.

Comment: @trashgod though a nice article, the only thing it shows it that tweaking painting et al doesn't buy you anything (except pain in future ;-) Even Scotty - one of the authors - admitted that (can't find the corresponding forum post on java.net, though)

Comment: @kleopatra: Agreed; it's as much a cautionary tale as a guide.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by others: have you tried profiling ? I personally have good experiences with JProfiler.

Although we do not yet know whether the `JTable` is the actual problem, I had performance problems with `JXTable`s (note: the SwingX version of `JTable`) in combination with large `TableModel`s where the table would iterate over all elements to determine the column size before painting it.

This was solved by setting a prototype value for each column (using `TableColumnExt#setPrototypeValue`). I am not sure whether a regular `JTable` contains this logic as well, but it might be worth a try to replace your `JTable` by a `JXTable` and set the prototype.